# Nil is returned everytime I try to access textLabel of UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am trying to get the text of the UITableViewCell in my

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    let cellLabel = selectedCell!.textLabel!.text
    print(cellLabel)
 }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let musicCell = music[indexPath.row]

     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MusicCell") as! MusicCell

     cell.setMusic(music: musicCell)

     return cell
}
```

but its returning nill.

MusicListView is my UIViewController and I have extended it

```
extension MusicListView: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You should be getting the data from your data model, not the cell.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that ?

Comment: As rmaddy says, you should be fetching data for the selected cell from your data model, not from your cell. As for why your code isn't working, you should break it down so that each step is on a separate line and then step through it in the debugger. Looking at your use of the force-unwrap `!` operator I would expect your code to crash rather than printing nil. (I call the `!` operator the "crash if nil operator".) Until you really understand Swift Optionals you should avoid using the `!` operator.

Comment: Show us your tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) method,

Comment: For readability, can you aadd that to your post please?

Comment: I have added it @onnoweb

Comment: So I'm assuming that in cell.setMusic() you set the the text of your textLabel?

Comment: @onnoweb yes i set the label and the image of it

Comment: thanks to rmadddy and  @DuncanC for you help I finally got it to work

Comment: So post an answer to your own question explaining what you changed, and including enough information for others to be able to understand the problem and its solution. Remember this site helps others, not just the person who originally asks a question.

Answer (score 0):

So as suggested by others I accessed the required data from the data model. 
I wrote a little function to access the data model

```
func findMusic(id : Int) -> String {
    currentTitle = songList[id].title!
    return currentTitle
}
```

and called it everytime a user tapped on a cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    currentTitle = findMusic(id: indexPath.row)
    playSong(title: currentTitle)
 }
```